# Which of the following is true

Tags: calculus

I was just handed this question involving the Intermediate Value Theorem and a continuous function. Now the problem says that we have $f\left(1\right)=-12$, $f\left(5\right)=7$, with $f$ being of course a continuous function on $\left[1,5\right]$. Now which of the following is true:

I) $f\left(x\right)=25$ does not have a solution on $\left[1,5\right]$.

II) $f\left(x\right)=17$ has a solution on $\left[1,5\right]$.

III) $f\left(x\right)=0$ has a solution on $\left[1,5\right]$.

And why? I'm getting the IVT mixed up with the mean value theorem, which finds the average on a selected (continuous) interval etc.

Answer (score 1):

III is true by the IVT since $0 \in (-12,7) = (f(1),f(5)) \Rightarrow \exists c \in (1,5): f(c) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

III)  Must be true.

Since $f(1)<0$  and $f(5)>0$ and f is continuous then by the intermediate value theorem $\exists x \in (1,5) : f(x)=0$.